# Component not rendering out buttons

Tags: reactjs, components, render

I'm trying to render out a few buttons, but for some reason nothing is happening.  I'm not certain where my mistake is.  I have an OverviewRender class which will eventually handle different sets of buttons to render and an Overview class which calls OverviewRender to render out the buttons.

It feels like should be working, but the buttons aren't rendering.  If I move the buttons inside the Overview return function I see can see them.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SearchBar from 'material-ui-search-bar'
import sass from '../scss/application.scss'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'


class OverviewRender extends Component {
    render() {
        const mainMenu = () => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <RaisedButton label="File Options" 
                        style={{ 
                            height: '80px',
                            width: '180px',
                            fontSize: '44px',
                            padding: '1px'}}
                            /> 
                    <RaisedButton label="Setup Options" 
                        style={{ 
                            height: '80px',
                            width: '180px',
                            fontSize: '44px',
                            padding: '1px'}}
                            />
                    <RaisedButton label="More Options" 
                        style={{ 
                            height: '80px',
                            width: '180px',
                            fontSize: '44px',
                            padding: '1px'}}
                            /> 
                </div>
            )
        }       
        return (
            <div>
                {mainMenu}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class Overview extends Component {
    constructor(props){
            super(props)
                this.state = {
                    open: false
                }
            }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="menuButtons">
                <OverviewRender />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Overview;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have created a function `mainMenu` that creates your buttons, but you never call it.

Two options:

**1.** Move the `mainMenu` return contents directly into the div:

```
class OverviewRender extends Component {
    render() {     
        return (
            <div>
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="File Options"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="Setup Options"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="More Options"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**2.** Move `mainMenu` out of the component to make it a functional component, which looks like what you are trying to achieve. And then you have to use it like you would any other component: `<MainMenu />`:

```
class OverviewRender extends Component {
    render() {     
        return <MainMenu />
    }
}

const MainMenu = () => (
    <div>
        <RaisedButton 
            label="File Options"
            style={{
                height: '80px',
                width: '180px',
                fontSize: '44px',
                padding: '1px'
            }}
        />
        <RaisedButton 
            label="Setup Options"
            style={{
                height: '80px',
                width: '180px',
                fontSize: '44px',
                padding: '1px'
            }}
        />
        <RaisedButton 
            label="More Options"
            style={{
                height: '80px',
                width: '180px',
                fontSize: '44px',
                padding: '1px'
            }}
        />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: I know I can get it to work with the div content directly in the component, but I am trying to achieve something more like your 2nd example.  Eventually I will pass in a name to render a certain set of buttons.  I think it would be handled better with a Render component or maybe a container.

Comment: It's working here in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/83744/). Might be something with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

#### User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized

> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

Just rename `mainMenu` to `MainMenu` an it should work.

See the docs: [component must be capitalized](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

```js
class OverviewRender extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const MainMenu =  ({name}) => (
                <div>
                    <button label="File Options" 
                        style={{ 
                            height: '80px',
                            width: '180px',
                            fontSize: '44px',
                            padding: '1px'}}
                            /> 
                    <button label="Setup Options" 
                        style={{ 
                            height: '80px',
                            width: '180px',
                            fontSize: '44px',
                            padding: '1px'}}
                            />
                    <button label="More Options" 
                        style={{ 
                            height: '80px',
                            width: '180px',
                            fontSize: '44px',
                            padding: '1px'}}
                            /> 
                </div>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                <MainMenu/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( < OverviewRender / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Still not what he's after. He needs `mainMenu` to be a function that he can pass a `name` prop into and do some conditional rendering. All you've done here is assign some html to a variable.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda sorry I updated my answer ( again), his main issue is cussed because  `mainMenu` is lowercase and it should be `MainMenu`, please see the docs: [component must be capitalized](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Comment: Yeah that was one of the many problems lol you're updated answer looks good, although ideally you should move the `MainMenu` function out of the component.

Comment: Yes I agree :) ^^